# Cheerio doesn't wait for body to load

Tags: cheerio

I made a very simple script which scrape a recipes website to get the title, time of preparation and the ingredients. Everything works fine except that the script is not able to scrape each page of my arrays. Sometimes i get 4 of them, sometimes 2, sometimes even 0 ...

It seems that the script doesn't wait the body to be fully loaded. I'm fully aware that cheerio doesn't understand javascript on website, but for all i know the information I scrape aren't generated from any script, it is pure HTML.

How can i ask cheerio to wait 1 second when a page is visited, or simply to wait for the html to be fully loaded.

Here is my code, it works so you can try it, and an example of the output :

```js
pools = [
     "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_salade-de-betteraves-a-l-orientale_16831.aspx",
     "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_pain-d-epices-a-la-dijonnaise_16832.aspx",
     "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_tarte-au-chocolat-et-creme-moka_16834.aspx",
     "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_poulet-a-la-gaston-gerard_16836.aspx",
   "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_assiette-paula_16837.aspx"]

    var request = require("request");
    var cheerio = require("cheerio");
    var poolsLength = pools.length;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < pools.length ; i++) {
       var url = pools[i];
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body,{
          ignoreWhitespace: true
    });
       var name = [];
       var address = [];
       var website = [];

    $('body').each(function(i, elem){
          name = $(elem).find('.fn').text();
          address = $(elem).find('.preptime').text();
          website = $(elem).find('.m_content_recette_ingredients').text();
          console.log(name+"±"+address+"±"+website);}
     )}
    })
    };`
```

As you can see above, it only worked for 2 of 5 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code, the setTimeout will cause a delay for the page to load before scraping.

```
pools = [
         "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_salade-de-betteraves-a-l-orientale_16831.aspx",
         "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_pain-d-epices-a-la-dijonnaise_16832.aspx",
         "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_tarte-au-chocolat-et-creme-moka_16834.aspx",
         "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_poulet-a-la-gaston-gerard_16836.aspx",
       "http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_assiette-paula_16837.aspx"]

        var request = require("request");
        var cheerio = require("cheerio");
        var poolsLength = pools.length;
        var interval = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < pools.length ; i++) {
           var url = pools[i];
           setTimeout( function (i) {
            request(url, function (error, response, body) {
             if (!error) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body,{
              ignoreWhitespace: true
        });
           var name = [];
           var address = [];
           var website = [];

        $('body').each(function(i, elem){
              name = $(elem).find('.fn').text();
              address = $(elem).find('.preptime').text();
              website = $(elem).find('.m_content_recette_ingredients').text();
              console.log(name+"±"+address+"±"+website);}
         )
        }
        }, interval * i, i);
        })
        }
```

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what i was looking for :).

Comment: using setTimeout to wait for definitely of time is not a good choice

Comment: @trungducng I totally agree, but since you're so sure of it, what would be your alternative?

Comment: You can use Array.reduce with Promise resolve to sequentially fetch the urls or maybe async await

Comment: @trungducng I like that, but why don't you post this as an answer? ;-)

Comment: So what's the point of setTimeout? To reduce load on the server? It's not clear why this should work.

Answer (score 0):

For handling many pages scrapping, just give a `callback` function to mark when the task is done, then using the `async.parallel` module to run.

My solution here:

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vfDnbjPw87/